# Navigation in Android Studio not working because of the code being in the onCreate Activity

Tags: android

[image]

Hello guys.
So when I try to click the "Enter" button on the image above, android shuts down due to something going on in the onCreate function which i'm not sure about, I've tested a blank page with the button above and it works perfectly; I know it has to do with the code inside the onCreate function, any idea how I can fix this? Thank you for any help Here's all the code:

(the host in the main_activity)

onCreate method for the calculator:

```
class calcFragment : AppCompatActivity() {



lateinit var operation: String
 var sNumber: Double = 0.0
 var fnumber: Double = 0.0


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calc)

    dot.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "."
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }

    zero.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "0"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    one.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "1"
        output.setText(oldvalue + set)
    }
    two.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "2"
        output.setText(oldvalue + set)
    }
    three.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "3"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    four.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "4"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    five.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "5"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    six.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "6"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    seven.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "7"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    eight.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "8"
        output.text = oldvalue + set
    }
    nine.setOnClickListener {
        val oldvalue = output.text.toString()
        val set = "9"
        output.setText(oldvalue + set)
    }

    plus.setOnClickListener {
        var value = output.text.toString()
        Log.i("x", "This is $value")
        var number = value.toDouble()
        fnumber = number
        output.text = ""
        operation = "+"


    }
    subtract.setOnClickListener {
        val value = output.text.toString()
        val number = value.toDouble()
        fnumber = number
        output.text = ""
        operation = "-"
    }
    multiplication.setOnClickListener {
        val value = output.text.toString()
        val number = value.toDouble()
        fnumber = number
        output.setText("")
        operation = "*"
    }

    division.setOnClickListener {
        val value = output.text.toString()
        val number = value.toDouble()
        fnumber = number
        output.setText("")
        operation = "/"
    }

    mod.setOnClickListener {
        val value = output.text.toString()
        val number = value.toDouble()
        fnumber = number
        output.setText("")
        operation = "%"
    }

    equals.setOnClickListener {
        try {
            if (operation == "+") {
                val value = output.text.toString()
                sNumber = value.toDouble()
                var system = fnumber + sNumber
                input.text = "$fnumber + $sNumber"
                output.text = system.toString()
                val result = fnumber + sNumber
                output.text = result.toString()
            } else if (operation == "-") {
                val value = output.text.toString()
                sNumber = value.toDouble()
                var system = fnumber - sNumber
                input.text = "$fnumber - $sNumber"
                output.text = system.toString()
                val result = fnumber - sNumber
                output.text = result.toString()
            } else if (operation == "*") {
                val value = output.text.toString()
                sNumber = value.toDouble()
                var system = fnumber * sNumber
                input.text = "$fnumber * $sNumber"
                output.text = system.toString()
                val result = fnumber * sNumber
                output.text = result.toString()
            } else if (operation == "/") {
                val value = output.text.toString()
                sNumber = value.toDouble()
                if (sNumber.equals(0)) {
                    val no = "CAN'T DIVIDE BY ZERO"
                    output.text = no
                } else {
                    val value = output.text.toString()
                    sNumber = value.toDouble()
                    var system = fnumber / sNumber
                    output.text = system.toString()
                    input.text = "$fnumber / $sNumber"
                    val oldoutP = output.text.toString()
                    oldoutP.toDouble()
                    val result = fnumber / sNumber
                    output.text = result.toString()
                }
            } else if (operation == "%") {
                val value = output.text.toString()
                sNumber = value.toDouble()
                var system = fnumber % sNumber
                output.text = system.toString()
                val result = fnumber % sNumber
                output.text = result.toString()
            }
        }
        catch (e: ArithmeticException){
            println("pressed enter without a value")
        }

    }
```

This is the code for my Navigation graph:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calcFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectone.calcFragment"
        android:label="fragment_calc"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calc" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectone.loginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_calcFragment"
            app:destination="@id/calcFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Here's the log file:

```
> 10/19 11:14:00: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 30.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.projectone/com.example.projectone.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 15505 on device 'Pixel_3a_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/mple.projecton: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/mple.projecton: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/mple.projecton: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/mple.projecton: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xefbd2df0, tid 15533
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xef9ded20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xef9ded20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xefd39f70) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xefbd4050, tid 15533
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fa6c3000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projectone, PID: 15505
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.projectone.calcFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:935)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:868)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:854)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:842)
        at com.example.projectone.loginFragment$onViewCreated$1$1.onClick(loginFragment.kt:49)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15505 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post your debugger log message?

Comment: For starters, your `calcFragment` is not a fragment but an activity.

Comment: @LucaPizzini I just added the log

Comment: Start at step one. Figure out how to work with fragments.